# XSL include XSL to register namespaces to process xpath with prefixes of the included XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-namespaces, exslt

OK. I'm sorry for my writing but its very strange what I'm doing to get a xPath processed.
I'm using just the xsltproc, so only XSLT 1.0 and EXSLT are my tools.

I use one input xml file to get the further xml files which I have to also process.
This causes that I do not know the prefixes and the namespace in the xsl I'm applying.

Futher I have to use "xPathes" (which are stored as attributes) out of my input xml file.
So I have to use EXSLT to evaluate (dyn:evaluate function) xpathes on documents which are loaded to variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="importedDocument" select="document('importDoc.xml')" />
```

form the importDoc:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
  <bm:root xmlns:bm="http://my.bookmarks/ns/1.0" >
    ....
```

So after that I want to use a xpath ... something like that in my xslt:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   version="1.0"
    xmlns:rs="http://ns.zf.com/xmlmerger/ruleset" 
    xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="dyn rs exsl" >

   ....

     <xsl:variable name="xpath" select="bm:root/bm:bookmarks[4]/@xpath" />
     <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($importedDocument)">
        <xsl:if test="dyn:evaluate($xpath)" >
          <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(dyn:evaluate($xpath))" />
        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
```

But finally I got this message from

```
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
dyn:evaluate() : unable to evaluate expression 'bm:root/bm:bookmarks[4]/@xpath'
```

So I need something like "autoregister namespaces" ???
Or is it possible to use catalog files to fix that ???
Or maybe I can use some kinds of imports or includes ???

Best Regards

Markus

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the *namespace* to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   version="1.0"
    xmlns:rs="http://ns.zf.com/xmlmerger/ruleset" 
    xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="dyn rs exsl"
    xmlns:bm="http://my.bookmarks/ns/1.0">
```

Actually, you can use any *prefix* you want in the stylesheet. The prefix that you declare is the one you use in your *XPath* selectors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can not add the namespace to the static xsl because the other xml files and the xpathes are dynamically  added to the transformation. So the basic xslt doesn't know the futher namespaces. So my question is **how to import namespaces**.

Comment: You *need* to register a prefix in order to be able to access an XPath expression such as `bm:root/bm:bookmarks[4]/@xpath`. This expression won't work if you do not register the `bm` prefix locally (in the stylesheet). If you don't wan't those prefixed in your result document, add the `exclude-result-prefixes="bm"` to your `xsl:stylesheet`.

Comment: The only other way to select the information you want without registering the namespace is to ignore it by rewriting *all* your XPath expressions with a predicate to select the element by its *local name*. Then `bm:root/bm:bookmarks[4]/@xpath` would become `*[local-name()='root']/*[local-name()='bookmarks'][4]/@xpath`

Comment: Sorry. That what I have to do is more advanced. As you can see the basic XSLT has no information about the incoming XML / XPATH and it is not possible to change the Xpathes. I also can not add the unknown namespaces to the xsl:stylesheet tag, because they are just in the source xml. Futher I use the EXSLT dyn:evaluate and exsl:node-set. Also the XML files (more than 1) are added by document() function. Maybe this will be the rigth question **Is it possible to import namespaces by using imported/included xslt files**